# Android: Eliminating the need for different build

Tags: android

I'm writing an app and the app will be used by the users of multiple clients / companies. At the moment how users authenticate is they would select the company name before they login. So high level flow would be:

> User launch app -> Select client (company A) -> Login with company A
>   details.

However this introduces privacy concern because it exposes all my client names. Another approach would be to prompt user to enter client name manually; but this is not a good option either because users are expected to switch from client to client quite regularly and it would be a hassle to them needing to type client name every time they switch client.

We have also explored the option of using QR code where users could select client by QR code; but this is not a viable option either because it's not easy to enforce every clients to have QR code placed in every corner of their premise.

Any other option that I could explore?

Comment: you can configure build variant for each your client companies https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants.html

Comment: How are you planning to distribute the app? Are all your clients using the same backend?

Comment: Yes. All the same backend. But will need client name so we could load client specific settings (background color, logo etc)